# Custom marker in google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add picture to marker in google maps. I want to show after clicked on marker picture and on right side of that picture some text. I create marker using this code:

```
Marker melbourne = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lblat,
                    lbLong))
            .title("Melbourne")
            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

but in that solution I have only title and snippet. How do marker on my way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to inflate your own layout of the `InfoWindow` with an `InfoWindowAdapter`. 
See the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows).

Here's a little example (I have this as an inner class in my map `Activity`):

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View v;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
        // set some bitmap to the imageview         

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And in your map `Activity`

```
gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your marker by using an image, you can add this image to the drawable folder, then:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(marq).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource((R.drawable.thenameofyourimage)))
```